# Searching a twitter list for certain tags or words

Tags: ruby, twitter, sinatra

I am learning ruby at the moment and using twitter as a platform to help me build my first prototype in Sinatra. I'm using the Twitter gem and have managed to get a private list of mine and display all the tweets related to the users in that list.

However I now want to search through the list for a set of certain set of keywords, and if found display the tweet.

Does anyone know if there is anyway within the Twitter gem to do this? Or how I would go about doing this in rails in an efficient way.

The only way I can figure out is to iterate through each tweet returned, get the text related to that tweet and search for the keywords, if found display that tweet. This to me is stupidly inefficient and would this not use up unnecessary API request?

This is what I have so far if this is of any help to anyone.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key       =  'xxxx'
  config.consumer_secret    =  'xxx'
  config.access_token        = 'xx'
  config.access_token_secret = 'xx'
end


get '/' do
  @tweet = client.list_timeline(1231123123123,{:include_rts => 0})
  erb :index
end
```

Many thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about this: iterate through each tweet returned, get the text related to that tweet and search for the keywords, if found display that tweet.

You wrote: "this to me is stupidly inefficient". You are correct. It's inefficient because you have to retrieve all the tweets, rather than just the tweets that contain the keywords that you want.

The Twitter gem does not do what you want, because Twitter search is slightly unpredictable. This is because the Twitter search is optimizing for relevancy, not thoroughness.

What you're looking for, I think, is Twitter "Streams". When you ask for a Twitter Stream, you get all the tweets from the user (or site, or globally). This is more sophisticated to set up. This gives you everything, and gives it to you in real time.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Then you search the tweets within Rails.

- If your want a simple search, you may want to look at using Ruby's `select` method and `Regexp` class.
- If you want powerful search capabilities, you may want to look at various search gems and search engines such as `sunspot_solr` and Lucene.
- If you're building a real-world business application with more advanced needs for scaling and searching, you may want to read about Twitter Firehose partners and text engines such as discovertext. These partners and engines provide real-time search APIs, caching, and many more features.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using search method as shown in [example here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Search.md)

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not allow search within a subset, plus as stated in the docs 
`Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.`

Comment: Don't point to off-site examples using a link only. *WHEN* the link breaks your answer will be useless. Instead, replicate the important part of that link in your answer, and explain why it will be useful to the OP.